# Getting a webpage to take up 60% and be centered?

Tags: html, css, alignment, frontend

I'm trying to create a website whose body up the middle 60%. I thought I'd do this:

```html
body {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60%;
}
```

But that's not working :(

I even tried using translateX to translate right 20%

Any advice? Suggestions?

Comment: you where only missing margin:auto; no need of a peticular display here, it is basic CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it easily using CSS grid. Here's the MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

Example:

HTML file

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS file

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this html code  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  Hello World !
</body>
```

And then this CSS :

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can try this [Website](https://jsfiddle.net/) to code html, css, and javascript online.

I hope I've helped you.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove width and instead use

```
 right: 20%;
 left : 20%;
```

It'll work I guess
And i think it would be better to use a div instead of body

Comment: hmm that didnt work for me :( but thank you